# difference between onclick and click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any kind of difference between the following two lines of code in JavaScript:

```
<button id='btn1' onclick='do_this();'>Button 1</button>;

<button id='btn1' click='do_that();'>Button 2</button>;

//some script later
function do_this()
{
    alert('this');
}

function do_that()
{
    alert('that');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onclick` works in javascript, `click` doesn't. If you want `click` to work, you might need jQuery.

Comment: Note that it should be `onclick`, not `onClick`. Attributes should be lower case.

Comment: @Eric: HTML is case-insensitive.

Comment: I said "should", not "must". It's good practice to code HTML with lower case attributes, as it makes it easy to convert into XHTML in the future.